# How do I apply css for thead on scroll?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a table and I want to apply `top` css for the `thead` of the table on scroll. I am having a trouble of executing it.

I tried `scroll` event but it didnt work. I tried of changing the css in DOM. At that time, its working. See the picture.

[image]

The same is not applying using javascript. This is my function:

```
$("#container").scroll(function(){
   $(".header").css({
      "position":"absolute",
      "top":"40px"
   });
});
```

What am I missing? Why is it not working using javascript? This is my Link [Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/7HMPdhQP2MhIcpb6Sbj4?p=preview)

Comment: Why don't you left the thead outside of your scrollable area? It seems that this is what you pretend...

Comment: If i do that, i will face many problem. This is just a sample table. In my project, i just want to change css of thead when scrolling.

Comment: Can you recreate this on jsfiddle or a similar site?

Comment: Missing `i` after `s` at `"postion":"absolute"`

Comment: Link added......@guest271314 by the way, the missing doesnt work :) Check the link

Comment: _"the missing doesnt work :) "_ ? `"postion"` should be `"position"`

Comment: Edited the missing. It didnt work. Check the link

Comment: @user4921393 Try substituting `$(this).scrollTop()` for `"40px"` at setting `top` ; see post , http://plnkr.co/edit/WzhvE8MRaaoAZzkJ0Jhe?p=preview . Note , `"postion"` is not a valid `css` property

Answer (score 0):

Try substituting `.scrollTop()` for `"40px"`

```
$(function() {
  $("#container").scroll(function() {
    $(".header").css({
      "position": "absolute",
      "top": $(this).scrollTop()
    });
  });
})
```

plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/WzhvE8MRaaoAZzkJ0Jhe?p=preview